# Which .Net library/project for facebook?

Tags: .net, asp.net, facebook

Which library/project is currently usable for creating Facebook applications?

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184880/which-facebook-net-library-is-the-best-to-use), where it seems like the projects mentioned in the original question have been abandoned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft recently released their [Microsoft SDK for Facebook Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/facebooksdk).

That seems to be the way to go now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Facebook Developer Toolkit has been abandoned as a new version is near release.  Check out this [blog entry](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/kevin_marshall/archive/2009/10/06/facebook-developer-toolkit-3-0-asp-net-mvc-sample.aspx).

Here is a tidbit from the post:

> It’s almost time for the long awaited release of the Facebook Developer Toolkit 3.0, the most awesomest release of the toolkit to date. The new version has great support for ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, Silverlight, WinForms, WPF and basically any place you can run .NET. Ryan Powers and I worked on adding MVC support last week. (actually Ryan did all the coding, I just advised). We are going to build out more samples because that seems to have been a slight problem in previous versions.