# Which SDK to use for Asp.Net with Facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am working on a Facebook canvas flash app and my server is in Asp.Net 2.0. I checked the facebook developer wiki and it seems like there are different Asp.Net SDKs [available](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:ASP.NET). Please suggest me which is the best one.

Comment: Your URL doesn't work. Don't use UR: shortening sites on stackoverflow. It's not twitter; you don't have character limitation.

Comment: I just checked and the URL is working fine for me.. The full URL is http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

You can call Facebook api function through url in code behind like this

```
 string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/friends?access_token=" +oAuthToken;  

 string results = string.Empty;

 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
 results = sr.ReadToEnd();
 sr.Close();
```

"result" will be in the form of Json object, you can parse it to get the data. Above example will get you details of friends of the specified "userid" with "access_token".

Answer (score 0):

If your application is in Flash, then it doesn't matter that your server supports ASP.NET.  You'll need to use a Flash or ActionScript SDK instead.  Try http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/.

Comment: My application is in Flash but I need to do few server side coding which also requires few FB api calls..

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend http://facebooknet.codeplex.com/ which is written by nikhil kothari and you will find good sample code as well.
Also look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184880/which-facebook-net-library-is-the-best-to-use):

Comment: This SDK is very old and currently not being maintained. Check out http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com for an sdk that supports oauth and the graph api.