# Facebook C# Library

Tags: c#, facebook, .net-3.5

Does anybody know of a good library out there for developing for Facebook using the REST API in C#.  I've been using the [Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/) for some time now, but have more recently become annoyed at how key functionality is broken (even in the updated 3.1 beta). I looked into using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/), but this only appears to have a version for .NET 4.0.

Comment: So, which legacy version of .NET are you looking for a library for? :)

Comment: Haha, sorry, I need something for .NET 3.5. Our WCMS is shaky at best with 4.0 so we haven't been able to upgrade yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com) says

Note: If you are looking for the WP7, Silverlight, .Net 35 builds of this project you will need to download the latest source and run the Build/runbuild.cmd. These builds are currently not in our "supported" release, but they should work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Having worked extensively with the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) I can confirm that there is a 3.5 build in the latest version, you just need to run the build scripts. There are also numerous discussions on how exactly to get it to build properly.

I have found through all my research that this SDK is the most rapidly updated and dependable SDK for .NET. If you have any problems using it then just drop a question on stackoverflow with the tag `facebook-net-sdk` and I'd be happy to answer

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook#](http://github.com/prabirshrestha/FacebookSharp) is pretty good, though I had to workaround a few things.

You might not want to use the REST API, though; they're deprecating it and bits of it may stop working...