# Facebook Development asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, desktop-application

I have a problem that I need to send a message to some of my friends on facebook and it is wasting time to send message individually to each one

also I want to be able to send a post that including Image and text to some facebook groups for marketing purpose to my facebook page

So I think that I can find a program that can help me do that or even some code example that can do that, or may be I will need to make my own program, but I never deal with facebook platform before

so please if any one can help I will be thankful

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184880/which-facebook-net-library-is-the-best-to-use

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward with Windows PowerShell and http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com. For example

Get-Friends | Show-FBMessageDialog -Link http://www.example.com

displays a dialog to send a message to all your friends (or you can add a filter to the command). I have used this to send a message to over a thousand people. This is not completely automated (Facebook API restriction), it will show one dialog for each 50 recipients.